# IE 10 - Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, web-applications, callback

We have a report builder in one of our apps that was built in .NET 2.0

Whenever we try to run a report in IE 10 we get a server error with the following message:

```
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using 
<pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or 
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  
For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback 
events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is 
valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in 
order to register the postback or callback data for validation. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web 
request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it 
originated in the code. 


Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.      
Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> 
in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security   
purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate 
from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and 
expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to 
register the postback or callback data for validation.

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. 
Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using   
the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 

[ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled 
using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page 
EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies 
that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that 
originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the 
ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback 
or callback data for validation.]
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument) +8636377
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +360
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +343
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1743


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5420; ASP.NET      
Version:2.0.50727.5420
```

This error is happening ONLY when we run the reports in IE 10.

If we use any other IE version or any other browser, we don't get any error and the report runs fine.

According to Microsoft documentation this is solved on .NET 3 and above. But we already have .NET 3.5 and still doesn't work on IE 10.

This is the page header:

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" Language="VB"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Client_Id.Value = Request.QueryString("Client_Id")
    Project_Id.Value = Request.QueryString("Project_Id")
    System_Id.Value = Request.QueryString("System_Id")
    Report_Page_Heading.Text = Replace(Request.QueryString("H"), "'", "")


    PartExportFields.SelectParameters.Add("Client_Id", Replace(Client_Id.Value, "'", ""))
    PartExportFields.SelectParameters.Add("Project_Id", Replace(Project_Id.Value, "'", ""))
    PartExportFields.SelectParameters.Add("System_Id", Replace(System_Id.Value, "'", ""))

    SavedCustomReports.SelectParameters.Add("Client_Id", Replace(Client_Id.Value, "'", ""))
    SavedCustomReports.SelectParameters.Add("Project_Id", Replace(Project_Id.Value, "'", ""))
    SavedCustomReports.SelectParameters.Add("System_Id", Replace(System_Id.Value, "'", ""))

    ListBox1.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString("edit")
End Sub

Protected Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation("Client_Id", Replace(Client_Id.Value, "'", ""))
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation("Project_Id", Replace(Project_Id.Value, "'", ""))
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation("System_Id", Replace(System_Id.Value, "'", ""))
    MyBase.Render(writer)
End Sub    
</script>
```

Any ideas or help would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found for this was running Windows Update.

This downloaded all necessary fixes for IE.

The error was gone after that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with IE 10.  IE 10 doesn't play nice with webforms (ironic that Microsoft technology doesn't work with Microsoft technology).  See this [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx).  There are some machine wide patches you can apply that can fix some problems.  Also, using some Microsoft Ajax stuff doesn't work at all with IE 10.  The only way I was able to fix that was to send a header telling IE to run the page in IE 9 mode.